# Do we need to use body-parser still?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have seen in many tutorials that people are using both express.json and bodyPaser.json middleware. Are they not doing the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

They don't just do the same thing, they *are* the same thing.

Express [has a dependency on body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3531987844e533742f1159b0c3f1e07fad2e4597/package.json#L33), and it [exposes body-parser through its own API](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3531987844e533742f1159b0c3f1e07fad2e4597/lib/express.js#L78).

If you're writing an Express app then the only reason to use body-parser directly is if, for some reason, you needed a newer version of it than Express provides.